# React.JS with Angular.JS: getInitialState called multiple times

Tags: javascript, angularjs, reactjs

I'm using angular.JS to render react components. My issue is that the react lifecycles are messed up.

Code in my Angular Controller:

```
app.controller('ApplicationListController', ['$location', function($location) { 
    ReactDOM.render(
        React.createElement(HeaderNavigation, { activePage: 'applicationList' }),
        document.getElementById('react-headear-navigation')
    );
}]);
```

**getInitalState** and **componentDidMount** (HeaderNavigation) within the react component get called everytime the user navigates (and the angular controller gets called again).

Btw. this happens for every react component that I use - so I don't think I need to provide any code from my react components. I think the issues is that I'm using Angular in a wrong way to render the react components.

Comment: mount them once, not each time. you're not using any DI on the component init anyway...

Comment: Thx but how do I mount the components only once?

Comment: move it out of the controller, there's no reason (shown) it needs to be there.

Comment: oh okay, I understand - but how shall I then set the "activePage" prop in my code shown above? I also have more controllers with more logic/props to be passed to the components

Comment: the "activePage" prop is a string, you can use strings anywhere. if it were a variable or something, then i can see why you wanted to put it in the controller. you still shouldn't, but it would make sense to try. if you have a dynamic value,  you really just need to update the props of your react components from inside the controller. your component should not be ugly on the page (or busted) before it has an  "activePage" prop, so you may need an IF of some sort...

Comment: okay, so basically what you're saying is I should render all components that I have for my app (regardless of the current route) on page init? My issue now (I tried to mount the component outside of the controller) is that the DOM element into which I'd like to render the component into doesn't exist yet (as the view hasn't been called by the angular controller yet) - every view has a different set of react-DOM targets :/

Comment: in that case, back into the controller, and my aforementioned IF needs to go around your render call so as not to render() something that's already there. but really, i think you might be going against the grain using the two enemies together like that, with each having to fight for ownership of a container.

Comment: okay, thanks for your help on this then! As I don't want to get off topic here, any hints on what to look for when it comes to proper react usage within frameworks? - I'd like to prevent using react for the entire page, only within certain parts. That's why I thought it might make sense to build it the way that i did.

Comment: yeah, i just don't know with that particular setup. the routing is the main issue i think. the other big issue is having dynamic containers for the react components. it might be best to render() relatively empty shells into a hidden container, and append them into the active view as needed, re-appending them to the hidden container when done. use `props` to push data from angular to the components and they will look correct.